# How to properly control execution flow Javascript Exception Handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

In the real code I fetch `accounts` from an SQL Database. Then, for every `account` of `accounts` I call some methods `a()`, `b()`, `c()`.

What I want Is that If for any reason an error (an exception) occurs while I'm calling `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, the execution halts and continue with the next iteration in the loop, that is, with the next account.

So, given that sample code:

```
const accounts = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

async function a() {
    await console.log('A');
}
async function b() {
    await console.log('B');
    throw new Error('B throws Error');
}
async function c() {
    await console.log('C');
}

async function main() {
    for (const account of accounts) {
        try {
            await a();
            await b();
            await c();
        } catch(e) {}
    }
}

main();
```

`a()` and `b()` Will get called, givin this output:

```
A
B
A
B
A
B
```

Then, If I add a try/catch in `b()`

```
async function b() {
    try {
        await console.log('B');
        throw new Error('B throws Error');
    } catch(e) {

    }
}
```

When running that code I would get:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

Despite an exception was thrown in `b()`, but `c()` got also executed due to the try/catch...

**My question is:**

> If I can't get the application to a reliable state in the catch... Is
>   there a way that I can keep using try/catch-s in the inner methods but
>   halting the execution so `c()` won't get executed ?

ps. If the way I'm using exceptions is just wrong. Would you help to shed some light to a correct usage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can't get the application to a reliable state in the catch... Is there a way that I can keep using try/catch-s in the inner methods but halting the execution so c() won't get executed ?

Yes, just rethrow the exception in `b()`, allowing it to be seen by the caller of `b()`.  It works exactly the same for `async` functions and promise `.then()` handlers as it does in the synchronous exception world.  This was purposely designed this way to give a similar feel for promise-based async/await exception/rejections.

```
async function b() {
    try {
        await console.log('B');
        throw new Error('B throws Error');
    } catch(e) {
        // pseudo code for some condition that you test to determine
        // if you want to "eat" the error or let the caller see it
        if (can't continue safely) {
            // allow the exception to propagate to the caller
            throw e;    
        }
    }
}
```

I presume you know that `async` and `await` are for asynchronous operations which you don't actually show in your code.   Nobody would do `await console.log(...)` in  real code since that's a synchronous operation that does not return a promise so the use of `await` there is pointless.  I'm hoping you're doing this just for the purposes of a short demo.

Comment: **I thought that to rethrow would be a bad practice. Isn't it ? Maybe it's common and acceptable...**
And yes, I'm using awaits in console because in the real code I could be using functions that returns promises and getting values from them when they resolve.

Comment: @Jeflopo - Rethrow is how you do it. It is the appropriate way to catch the error, examine it or log it and then decide to let it propagate back to the caller.  **It's not a bad practice.  It is the correct practice if you need to catch it locally and then let it propagate back to the caller.** Sometimes, you don't catch it locally and just let it always propagate.  But, if you need to catch it locally for some reason, then rethrow is the only way to decide to let the caller see it.  It is common.

Comment: Oook. I was unsure about that... When you say *"propagate back to the caller"* In that case would be to the `for-of` context, where `b()` was called, in other words, the parent of `b()` in the execution flow, right ?

Comment: @Jeflopo - Yes, back to the code that called `b()`.  In your case, it would be caught by the try/catch block inside the `for` loop in `main()` because you used `await b()`.  So, the `await` will see the rejected promise come back from `b()` and will throw locally.